# Rename files and folders recursively depth first

Tags: bash

From another answer on this site I've gleaned the following snippet for renaming files recursively:

```bash
find . -iname "*oldName*" -exec rename oldName newName '{}' \;
```

This works great if you're only working on files. However, if you have a directory structure where directories also contain `oldName` that you want to change, this fails because it renames the directories first and then can't find the files to rename.

I can work round this by running the command twice, but that's not ideal.

Is there a way to modify the command to make it do this in a depth-first fashion to avoid this problem entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` has a `-depth` option which does exactly what you’re after:

```
find . -depth -iname "*oldName*" -exec rename oldName newName '{}' \;
```

Comment: Bang on, thanks mate